# Assigning fetched date from mysql in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have certain `date` saved in my `MySQL`, and i want to enable those dates in my `jQuery datepicker` and disable rest `date`.

Here is my Try :

my date after being fetched from `mysql` is :-

1). From `07-07-2014` to `15-07-2014`

2). `23-08-2014`

3). From `25-08-2014` to `26-08-2014`

And to store it in `jQuery datepicker`, Below is javascipt code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var availableDates = [9,14,15]; //desired Days
    var availableMonth = [1,5,7]; //desired Month
    var availableYear = [2014,2015]; //desired Year
    function available(date) {
       dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
       if (jQuery.inArray(date.getDate(), availableDates) != -1 && $.inArray((date.getMonth()+1), availableMonth) != -1 && $.inArray(date.getFullYear(), availableYear) != -1) {
          return [true, "","Available"];
       } else {
         return [false,"","unAvailable"];
       }
    }
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });
</script>
```

Current Script is enabling only above dates in every month, but i want it to be some dynamic date for every month. For that i tried to create below object, but am not sure how to implement it.

```
var availableTime = {
    '2014' : {
        '07' : ['07', '08', '09', '10'],
        '08' : ['01', '02', '05']
    },
    '2015' : {
        '02' : ['11', '18', '19', '21'],
        '03' : ['21', '22', '25']
    }
};
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    for(var j in obj )
    {
        for(var p in obj[j] )
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < obj[j][p].length; i++ )
            {
                 console.log(obj[j][p][i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can i implement, them ?

datepicker in question is from here : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

building on what you did, you can make your available function look something like that:

`availableTime` is the array that will have all the available dates as you mentioned above. This array can be built with an ajax call or on the server side when you are rendering your view.

once you have that array in the client side, the available function below is used to check if any given date is allowed or not by looking for it in the `availableTime` array.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6v9HR/7/).

```
// The map of specific available dates by month and year
var availableTime = {
    '2014': {
        '7': ['7', '8', '9', '10'],
        '8': ['1', '2', '5']
    },
    '2015': {
        '2': ['11', '18', '19', '21'],
        '3': ['21', '22', '25']
    }
};

function available(date) {
    var d, m, y, availableDates = [];
    d = date.getDate().toString();
    m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    y = date.getFullYear();
    if (availableTime[y] && availableTime[y][m]) {
        /* 
         * Get available dates of this specific month and year from
         * the map defined above
         */
        availableDates = availableTime[y][m];
    }

    // return true if that day is allowed in the specific dates
    var available = (jQuery.inArray(d, availableDates) > -1);
    if (available) {
        return [true, "", "Available"];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
    }
}

jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: available
});
```

so basically the specific day ( d ) of specific ( m ) or that year ( y ) is not null. It will return true.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? There has to be input from `mysql` database, whose dates, month and year will be stored in array, and those date needs to be checked with calendar date in datepicker.

Comment: I can't understand your variable `availableTime`. This variable is not created ?

Comment: I added a working example. That should let you understand it better.